# Alarm is not successfully created using openstack4j library

Tags: openstack, openstack4j

I have created an alarm using openstack4j as follows:

```
 Alarm alarm2 = os
    .telemetry()
    .alarms()
    .create(alarm);
    System.out.println("Alarm details:"+alarm.getAlarmId());
    System.out.println("alarms:"+os.telemetry().alarms().list());
```

But after alarm is created the AlarmId is null and is also not found in the list of alarms.
There are no errors during the creation of alarms also.

Openstack4j Version used is: 3.0.4-SNAPSHOT

Comment: After further analysis ,found that the url request to create the alarm from openstack4j is http://172.16.1.100:8777/v2/alarms instead of http://172.16.1.100:8042/v2/alarms.

Alarm service is running on 8042 and not on 8777.

Comment: i checked the port value in the /etc/ceilometer/ceilometer.conf file and it reads 8777.But still i am facing the same issue